# Setting the space between fixed page header and float text block

Tags: spacing, header-footer, itemize

I searched for previous answers, but none solves my question about how to set the space between **fixed** page header and float text block.

```
    \headsep changes the position of header, rather than the position of text block.
```

Specifically to my problem: I have a two page document. At the end of the fist page, I defined an item list

```
   ...
   \begin{itemize}
       \item A 
       \item B
   \end{itemize}
   ....
```

Due to contents reasons, Item A appears at the bottom of the first page, while Item B appears at the top the second page. Suppose the page margins, header and foot positions are all fixed, and contents on the first page is unchangable. How can I adjust (enlarge) the space between page 2 header and Item B? They overlapped, and I want Item 2 to go down a little bit. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "float" in your title (I expected a question about floats (figure/table) but apparently not? In your example B will just go where first lines of any page will go, so if that is overlapping the header your header setup is wrong probably `\headheight` is incorrect but it is hard to say without an example document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much, but let's forget about float problem. Is it possible to keep the header fixed and let Item B go to the second line or third line while leaving the first line or first&second line blank?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey, David, you were right, it is the problem of header setup, and probably also because I used a \tikzpicture to draw frames. Problems solved. Thank you anyway. Next time when I ask questions I will try to use a MWE~

Comment: OK Glad you got it working, I guess this is a duplicate in that case so we can close rather than answer here.